# What is the meaning of a <CR> at the end of some vim mappings?

Tags: vim, mapping

I see `<cr>`s a lot in vim mappings, but what does it do?

Comment: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#<>

Answer (score 162, accepted):

```
:help key-notation
```

says:

```
notation    meaning            equivalent  decimal    value(s)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
<CR>        carriage return        CTRL-M    13       *carriage-return*
<Return>    same as <CR>                              *<Return>*
<Enter>     same as <CR>                              *<Enter>*
```

Mappings often involve Ex commands and you must press `<CR>` to execute them so it's included in the mapping.

Comment: Upvoted for showing how to get to the information! That's the way to learn two things at once :-)

Answer (score 13):

#### Why `<special keys>`?

While you can use literal keys in mapping definitions (the Enter key would appear as `^M`, or even just as an additional new line, depending on the settings), Vim provides a special key notation for key (combinations), so that it is easier to define (you don't have to use `i_CTRL-V` to literally insert the special character) and understand (`<A-a>` better expresses the intention than the equivalent `á`) the mappings.

See `:help key-notation` for a list and explanation.

#### Why `<CR>`?

As many mappings invoke Ex commands (e.g. `:w`) and therefore have to switch from *normal* to *command-line* mode, they have to conclude the command with `<Enter>` (or `<CR>`), just as you would when manually typing the command.

Answer (score 12):

The `<CR>` in `vim` mappings is the [carriage return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) usually the <kbd>Enter</kbd> on your keyboard.

Answer (score 6):

`<CR>` in a mapping corresponds to the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key just like `a` in a mapping corresponds to the <kbd>A</kbd> key. Ley's say you have this mapping

```
:map <f8> :wq<cr>
```

This will map <kbd>F8</kbd> to the key sequence <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>W</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> (which would save the current buffer and quit).

Answer (score -1):

It's basically a means to say "this is the end", see [map](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html):

> When you have a mapping that contains an [Ex](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#Ex) command, you need to put a line
>   terminator after it to have it executed.  The use of  is recommended for
>   this. Example:
>
> > `:map  _ls  :!ls -l %<CR>:echo "the end"<CR>`

also,

```
<CR>    [count] lines downward, on the first non-blank character |linewise|.
```